# How to upgrade PHP to specific version?

Tags: ubuntu, php

I have PHP 5.3.5 on Ubuntu Sever and I need to have exactly 5.3.8. How can I do such an upgrade?

ps. Just question just earned "notable question" badge, any reasons for the downvotes?

Comment: How about "this question does not show any research effort"?

Answer (score 1):

We first have to resolve two dependencies required for the dotdeb packages. If you are running the amd64 version, you should replace i386 with amd64.

```
cd /tmp

wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/k/krb5/libkrb53_1.6.dfsg.4~beta1-5ubuntu2_i386.deb

wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu38_3.8-6ubuntu0.2_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

We'll have to add the dotdeb repository to the APT sources, so we can use their packaged PHP 5.3 and php-fpm:

```
sudo echo "deb http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Update apt:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The resulting text should include dotdeb.

Now we'll install PHP (part 1):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli php5-common php5-suhosin
```

Answer (score 0):

download from php.net and compile.
or http://www.dotdeb.org/2011/08/30/php-5-3-8-is-available/

Comment: compiling is a bad thing (tm)

Comment: @GioMac [Nothing wrong with compiling things yourself if you know what you're doing](http://youtu.be/7R6_Chr2vro?t=12s)

Comment: Yes it is wrong! You will never know, even if you are Zend employee: how many binary files will you get, where will "make install" put them, how to upgrade them (which files to remove, which to leave), you cannot be sure how "make uninstall" and "make install" will upgrade it, you do not know which files were changed by you. YOU JUST CANNOT KNOW THAT. This is why packaging like RPM and DPKG is used. Compile in RPM, not in the air.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should search from some Ubuntu custom repositories which already has latest PHP versions and maybe also PHP beta versions and you can install it from there without the hassle of downloading and compiling it manually.

Comment: But how do I specify to install the version I need? E.g. now I have 5.3.5, but want 5.3.3?

Comment: what ubuntu version are you using? i386 or amd64?